# Return http 204 "no content" to client in ASP.NET MVC2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, httpresponse

In an ASP.net MVC 2 app that I have I want to return a 204 No Content response to a post operation. Current my controller method has a void return type, but this sends back a response to the client as 200 OK with a Content-Length header set to 0. How can I make the response into a 204?

```
[HttpPost]
public void DoSomething(string param)
{
    // do some operation with param

    // now I wish to return a 204 no content response to the user 
    // instead of the 200 OK response
}
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

In MVC3 there is an [HttpStatusCodeResult class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.httpstatuscoderesult%28v=vs.98%29.aspx). You could roll your own for an MVC2 application:

```
public class HttpStatusCodeResult : ActionResult
{
    private readonly int code;
    public HttpStatusCodeResult(int code)
    {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext context)
    {
        context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = code;
    }
}
```

You'd have to alter your controller method like so:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DoSomething(string param)
{
    // do some operation with param

    // now I wish to return a 204 no content response to the user 
    // instead of the 200 OK response
    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
}
```

Answer (score 25):

You can simply return a IHttpActionResult and use `StatusCode`:

```
public IHttpActionResult DoSomething()
{
    //do something

    return StatusCode(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NoContent);        
}
```

Answer (score 22):

### Update as of ASP.NET Core 1.0+ (2016)

You can return a [`NoContent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.nocontent) ActionResult.

```
[HttpPost("Update")]
public async Task<IActionResult> DoSomething(object parameters)
{
    // do stuff
    return NoContent();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI, i am using your approach and it is returning 204 No Content (just return a void), i think you have another problem

```
[HttpPost]
public void SetInterests(int userid, [FromBody] JObject bodyParams)
{
     ....
     .....

    //returning nothing
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using MVC, not WebAPI?

Comment: WebAPI @SlimShaggy

Comment: in Web API void methods return 204, but in MVC they return 200.

Comment: How do you comunicate an error? Like if ( somethingWentWrong) return 400 else return 204

Answer (score 0):

For .net 6 plus the new approach is

```
        public IActionResult MyAction()
        {
            return NoContent();
        }
```