# How to use BeginForm without a View? mvc.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view

I would like to use BeginForm to send some data to the server to check them without reloading the page.

If my action is of type void i get a blank page, same when i use EmptyResult.
Also tried with Html.BeginForm, same result.

Here's the Code:

view:

```
@using(Ajax.BeginForm("putData", "Home", null,  new AjaxOptions {HttpMethod = "POST" }, new { target = "_self" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(false)
    <fieldset style="padding-bottom: 0" id="Settings">
        <legend>Settings</legend>
        ....
                <td width="180" align="right" class="noborder">
                    <button type="submit" id="checkButton">Check</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </fieldset>
}
```

controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public EmptyResult putData(Settings settings)
{
    ...some checking and updating the model
    return new EmptyResult();
}
```

Hope you guys can help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return http 204 "no content" to client in ASP.NET MVC2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4513583/return-http-204-no-content-to-client-in-asp-net-mvc2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the HTTP 204 No Content status code:

```
return new HttpStatusCodeResult(204);
```